# Create ZIP only when files are found - using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zip, find

I want to create a ZIP based on the results from find command. But an error is thrown when zip command does not have any content to zip.

```
find ${DIRECTORY_TO_SEARCH} -type f -mtime -7 | xargs zip "${ZIP_FILE}"
```

Error code thrown by zip command: ***zip error: Missing or empty zip file***

How can I ensure a ZIP is created only when the file count is more than 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU `xargs` you can use the `-r` switch:

> ```
> --no-run-if-empty
> -r    If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.
>       Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.
>       This option is a GNU extension.
> ```

Example:

```
$ echo "" | xargs echo "foo"
foo
$

$ echo "" | xargs -r echo "foo"
$
```

Comment: Thanks @adrian-fruhwirth, the following command did what I wanted. `find ${DIRECTORY_TO_SEARCH} -type f -mtime -7 | xargs -r zip "${ZIP_FILE}"`